# System.Net.HttpListner can not work using an adapter IP address

Tags: c#, vb.net

I tried creating an HTTP server using System.Net.HTTPListener, but it doesn't accept a request using the current adapter's IP address except localhost and 127.0.0.1.
I set my network adapter's IP address to 192.168.10.10. Ping is working fine.

Sample code is here:

```cs
    HttpListner ls = new HttpListner();
    ls.Prefixes.Add("http://+:2222/");
    ls.start(); 
    HttpListnerContext cntx = ls.GetContext();
```

Comment: It looks like you're missing a colon: `"http://+:2222/"`. Unsafe. It accepts any request sent to port `2222` (`http` only, without certificate).

Comment: Thanks Jimi and you are right it was a typing mistake but in my code the colon is available. And about the Safety, it is the next step, all i need now is to solve the responding problem using an Ip address rather than localhost and 127.0.0 1.

Comment: Why wouldn't it answer? Did you set up a static address? The DNS addresses are OK? Does `Tracert.exe` show some weird path if you trace the root to that address? Have you verified, with `netsh http show urlacl` whether you have more that one, maybe conflicting, ACL rule set on that prefix? Note that prefixes are unique per HttpListener (well, you should get an exception there). Maybe try to add one specific with `netsh http add urlacl url=http://+:2222/ user=Everyone`. Of course, using a WebBrowser or other Http client, you have to request a response from `http://192.168.10.10:2222/`

Comment: If localhost is set to the IP address of the computer you will get an error because client and server are using the same IP.  IP address could also be set to an IPV6 address which also will not work.

Comment: LOL, *trace the root* (from where...). *Trace the route*, of course :)

Comment: About the connection its well connected and I'm running the program as an Administrator to eliminate the conflict with  netsh. Besides i used TcpListener with IP address 0.0.0.0 and port 2222 and it worked fine. But I still don't get it why HttpListener is not working and TcpListener is working for the same Ip and port configuration.